# Search multiple columns for multiple variables and then split by variable name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Preface with the fact I'm a complete SQL noob, and I'm aware that this is supposedly quite a simple query however I can't find anything on here that has helped me. So thanks for your time.

I have several columns that have coded events happening to a person listed within them. And I want to search by the code (e.g. A106 or B465) to count the number of times an event has happened, no matter which column it is in. So essentially search all of the event columns and make a count of how many times 4 different events turn up, with the results split by the event code. What I have so far as my structure (which may or may not be right) is:

```
SELECT COUNT()
FROM EVENTSLOG
WHERE EVENT1 IN ('A106', 'A107', 'B465', 'E713') OR
EVENT2 IN ('A106', 'A107', 'B465', 'E713') OR
EVENT3 IN ('A106', 'A107', 'B465', 'E713') OR
EVENT4 IN ('A106', 'A107', 'B465', 'E713')
GROUP BY
```

I know this isn't much but I have about 100 other snippets that I've written, including trying to `UNION` all the columns (confused about keeping the associated primary key) every time I'm getting stuck onto how to split by the event code at the end.

Thanks :)

## Update:

What I'm hoping for is to get something like

```
Event Code   Number of Events
=========== =================
A106         554
A107         4233
B465         4196
E713         34
```

I am running the suggested code below but it is a huge data set (and I am actually searching 24 columns for 7 codes, and so far my query has been running for a very long time) - and I haven't had any output yet.

## 2nd edit

Okay just had the query results back from the suggested answer below.. and i got back the table outline I'm looking for but it is only giving a count of 1 for every code when I know there are more than that?
eg.

```
CODE   CNT
====  ====
A105   1
A106   1
B465   1
E713   1
F432   1
F465   1
K364   1
```

Comment: Could you post some sample schema and expected output based on that?

Comment: see here as well on ways to get help fast :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: This article might help you http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a union of all 4 columns:

```
select code, count(*) as cnt 
from(
     select event1 as code from log
     union all
     select event2 as code from log
     union all
     select event3 as code from log
     union all
     select event4 as code from log
    )t
where code in('A106', 'A107', 'B465', 'E713')
group by code
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried this but it is showing only a count of 1 for each of the event codes, when I know there are more times this code has shown up. Also side question, why is the 't' after the brackets required?

Comment: t is required by the syntax - you should alias a subquery. This select statement should work. Probably you are doing something wrong.